# can a css border start away from the corner?

Tags: css, border

Is it possible to have css borders starting away from the corner of the parent element?

I am in a situation where can't use padding to bring the width in because borders still go to the edge, and I can't use margin because I need the background colour to go to the edge.

I would really rather avoid another parent div if possible.

Comment: For a specific answer, show some code. For an even better answer, make a [jsFiddle test case](http://jsfiddle.net/). The more effort you put into your question, the better answer you're likely to get. Your question isn't fantastically detailed, hence the generalised answers.

Comment: I disagree thirtydot, it was fairly well explained. Although a coded example is always great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an alternative.  You will need to use another parent div.

Answer (score 1):

not possible - you will have to bite the bullet and spend another tag on your page

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add the extra markup, get the design to a place you think is ok, then add the extra divs with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that this can be done with pseudo elements, but this was not appropriate as I needed xBrowser compatibility.